# The game always crash after saving

Tags: prison-architect, ubuntu

I'm playing the latest alpha build of Prison Architect (alpha-20) on Ubuntu 14.04 via Steam. My problem is that the game always crash when I save the game or when the auto-save is triggered.

At the end of the `debug.txt` file located in `/home/epoc/.Prison Architect`, I found several lines that seems to be interresting :

```
WARNING in Image constructor : Failed to open file ''
WARNING: Failed to activate checkbox 'SortBy'
WARNING: Failed to activate checkbox 'SortBy'
WARNING in Image constructor : Failed to open file '/home/epoc/.Prison Architect/saves/epoc.png'
Saving map to '/home/epoc/.Prison Architect/saves/epoc.prison'...Save completed in 254ms (219ms to serialise world, 34ms to write file)
Created FrameBuffer of size 2048 x 1024 in 0ms
(WorldRenderer::RenderCellTypes GL ERROR 0x501
```

It seems that the game cannot create the preview image file of my prison. Several people on the Web have this problem, but I didn't found any solution.

Comment: I tried a chmod 0777 on the save directory, change nothing.

Comment: Also tried to manually create a dummy image file, the game still can't open it (but the image is shown on the Load game screen)

Comment: I have the same issue and already reported a [bug](http://bugs.introversion.co.uk/view.php?id=4014) describing it. This bug only happens with the 64bit binary. Try running 32bit (`~/.local/share/Steam/SteamApps/common/Prison\ Architect/PrisonArchitect.i686`) from the terminal and see if it works.

Comment: This bug is now officialy fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug [was marked](http://bugs.introversion.co.uk/view.php?id=4014) as fixed (awaiting feedback ATM) on the official PA bugtracker (the motherbug regarding all save crashs is [located here](http://bugs.introversion.co.uk/view.php?id=4823)).

**Edit :** This bug is now officialy fixed